# Change Slides order in Swiper.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, swiper.js

I need to change the order of the slides in the front-end, so my client can select the position/order of each slide.
I just realised that I could use the css flex box property "order: x" but it doesn't work fine if I have the Loop mode on.

```
<div class="jt-slider">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">

        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url(coming/jt_0.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url(coming/jt_1.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url(coming/jt_2.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url(coming/jt_3.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url(coming/jt_4.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url(coming/jt_5.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url(coming/jt_6.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url(coming/jt_7.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url(coming/jt_8.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url(coming/jt_9.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url(coming/jt_10.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url(coming/jt_11.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url(coming/jt_12.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url(coming/jt_13.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image: url(coming/jt_14.jpg)"></div>
    
    </div>
```

Thats the basic Swiper html structure, when the loop mode is rendered it copy all the divs and adds a class "swiper-slide-duplicate"

It's strange that Swiper doesn't have an specific option to reorder them independently after the render...

I'm using native JavaScript, Jquery and CSS

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: Where is the code? Add a code snippet so that we can have a look at it.

Comment: Not sure, what kind of languages you're using in your project, but if data is coming from DB and you have orders stored in DB then apply sorting in an HTML rendering.

Comment: @Cédric thanks, just added the code and a more accurate description

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

// first you have to get the maximum number of slides in your slider .

var maxslides = document.getElementById("maxSliedes").innerHTML;

// then you get randum number between 0 and maxslides number

var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxslides - 0 + 1)) + 0;

// after that by using initialSlide: randomnumber, you get each time you reload the page neu slide .

var swiper = new Swiper('.js-swiper--standard', {
initialSlide: randomnumber,
slidesPerView: 1,
centeredSlides: true,
spaceBetween: 10,
loop: true,
autoplay: {
delay: 5000,
disableOnInteraction: false,
},